# Invalid route action: [resources\views\livewire\product-index.blade.php]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-livewire

i've tried to make the view for my product,

product-index.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}" class="text-dark">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Product</li>
            </ol>
          </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<h2><strong>Art</strong>hestic</h2>
```

navbar.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('products') }}"  role="button"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Products
                    </a>
```

web.php
(when i use this route, it shows the error message 'Invalid route action: [resources\views\livewire\product-index.blade.php].

```
Route::get('/products', 'resources\views\livewire\product-index.blade.php')->middleware('auth')->name('products');
```

but when i use this one

```
Route::get('/products', App\Http\Livewire\ProductIndex::class)->middleware('auth')->name('products');
```

[it doesn't show anything, if there's no error it would show the text from my product-index.blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEjby.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form, and your attempts to resolve the error

Comment: Also, please edit your question to contain the **expected** behaviour. In the comments, you've mentioned that "my product wont show up", what does that mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase i already edited it

Comment: Can you share more details, like the content of `App\Http\Livewire\ProductIndex`? Also, have you treid to use a proper route action in `Route::get` and **not** a template name?

Comment: Does your body have a `{{ $slot }}`?  https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components

Comment: @m4rsy4 You should be able to use your `ProductIndex` class in the web.php file. Which versions of Laravel and Livewire are you using? And you can show up you ProductIndex class?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a view in your route. This should be a function.

```
Route::get('/products', function () {
    return view('product-index');
});
```

If your view needs data from your database, you should create a function in your controller that gets the data and returns it with the view. Then reference it in your routes file like below.

```
Route::get('/producs', 'App\Http\Controllers\CONTROLLERNAME@FUNCTIONAME');
```

Comment: i tried to fix my route like this

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::get('/products', App\Http\Livewire\ProductIndex::class)->middleware('auth')->name('products');`

but my product wont show up

this is my product-index.blade
`</div>
    <h2><strong>Art</strong>hestic</h2>
</div>`

Comment: @rpm192 your answer is tecnically correct but he should be able to attach his Livewire component with a route.

Answer (score 0):

The most [basic](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) Laravel routes accept a URI and a closure as a second parameter. Note no need to start path from `resources/views` as Laravel already knows where your views are.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/products', function () {
    return view('livewire.product-index'); 
});
```

or via Controller

```
use App\Http\Livewire\ProductIndex;

Route::get('/products', [ProductIndex::class, 'index']);
// where 'index' is method name inside App\Http\Livewire\ProductIndex class. Name could be any and it should return view.
```

**ProductIndex.php**

```
class ProductIndex
{
  public function index() {
    return view('livewire.product-index');
  }
}
```

If you need to pass a view as a second parameter change `get` method to `view` like said [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes)

```
Route::view('/products', 'livewire.product-index');
```